# The output of U command in Debug tool in MS-DOS

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, disassembly

I'm reading IBM PC Assembly language and programming book and in the third chapter I think, the author began to talk about debug tool that comes with MS-DOS. In the examples he used the `A` command to assemble a code then used the `U` command to unassemble the same code.

Lets assume that the code was like this:

*note : the starting address is set to 100 by starting the assemble command like that :* `A 100`

```
MOV ax, 20
MOV dx, 10
ADD ax, dx
NOP
```

The question is here, when he used `U` command to disassemble code from 100 where we started to 106 where we stopped the output contains about 5 columns.

I will copy it here, and hope you can explain what are these hex numbers:

```
`1`  `2`    `3`           `4`

073F:0100 B81000      MOV AX, 20
073F:0103 BB1000      MOV DX, 10
073F:0106 01C6        ADD AX, DX
073F:0108 90          NOP
```

Column 2 and 4 are clear and very straightforward, but what are those numbers in column 1 and 3?

Comment: 1,2 is memory address, 3 is byte code, 4 is disassembly of byte code?

Comment: @YOU do you mean 1,2 are just 1 column? 073F:0100 is not two things? just one thing, the memory address?

Comment: 0x073F0100 is real address, ':' is just for humans to understand clearly, imo.

Comment: In the old days the 20-bit address is made of two parts, a segment register and an offset in that segment (columns 1 and 2).To find the "actual" address you multiple the segment by 16 and add the offset. In the first line the address is thus `000074F0` (not `073F0100` as above).That means segments can align a paragraph of 16 bytes, and it follows there is more than one way to express an address. Things have moved on now, and the segment registers are no longer used directly. Column 3 is the byte code, for example the first instruction is `B8 10 00`. They have been run together in this column.

Answer (score 0):

(Column 1)*16 + Column 2 = The real address
Column 3 is the machine code
Column 4 is obviously the assembly code

Comment: It's not "the multiplication result".  It's `col1 * 16 + col2`.  IDK if you misunderstood Weather Vane's comment explaining this, or if you just chose the wrong words to describe it.  Also "machine code" would be a better description for col3.  "byte code" has a specific technical meaning other than "bytes of machine code".  (It means non-text input for an interpreter or JIT compiler, but not for hardware.  e.g. Java bytecode.)